# Changing div properties with javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make div height change with input so it can represent floors.

I dont really understand how to make a script variable represent an actual value, beacuse if i set

> document.getElementById("height_representation_floors").setAttribute("style","height: height_floor ");

to change to 500px or so it works just as intended.
What can i do?

```js
            function calculus_meters() {

                height_floor = 0

                height_input_code_meters = document.getElementById("height_input").value

                height_floor = height_input_code_meters / 2.7

                document.getElementById("height_representation_floors").setAttribute("style","height: height_floor ");

                document.getElementById("output").textContent = height_input_code_meters + ' meters of height is approximately ' + height_floor.toFixed(0) + ' floors of a regular living building'

            }
            function calculus_feet() {

                height_floor = 0

                height_input_code_feet = document.getElementById("height_input").value

                height_floor = height_input_code_feet / 8.86

                document.getElementById("output").textContent = height_input_code_feet + ' feet of height is approximately ' + height_floor.toFixed(0) + ' floors of a regular living building'

            }
```

```css
            body {  
                margin: 0;
                background: #595959;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            #output {
                position: absolute;
                font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;
                background: white;
                border: solid 2px black;
            }
            #button_1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 3vh; 
                left: 62vw;
            }
            #button_2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 3vh; 
                left: 69.7vw;
            }
            #height_representation_floors {
                position: absolute;
                top: 20vh;
                height: 1100px;
                width: 500px;
                background-image: url(images/height_representation.png);
            }
            #height_representation_stickman {
                position: absolute;

            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
       
    </head>
<body>
<div id="house_2">

    <div id="output" style="height: 5vh; width: 60vw; margin: 2vw; ">
    </div>

    <h1 style="position: absolute; left: 2vw; top: 8vh; text-align: left; font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;"> Input wanted height: </h1>

    <input type="number" step="any" id="height_input" style="position: absolute; margin: 2vw; top: 8vh; text-align: left; width: 60vw; height: 5vh; font-size: 2vw; border: solid 2px black;">

    <div id="button_1">
    <button type="button" onClick="calculus_meters()" style="width: 14.6vh; height: 14.6vh; border: solid 2px black; font-size: 1.5vw">Convert (in meters)</button>
    </div>

    <div id="button_2">
    <button type="button" onClick="calculus_feet()" style="width: 14.6vh; height: 14.6vh; border: solid 2px black; font-size: 1.5vw">Convert (in feet)</button>
    </div>

    <div id="height_representation_floors">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basic string concatenation, you clearly do string concatenation on the line below it with the variables when you set the textContent. But you really should not be using setAttributee to set styles.

Answer (score 0):

You should use template literals to concatenate the variable into the string:

```js
document.getElementById("height_representation_floors").setAttribute("style", height: `${height_floor}px`);
```

This will correctly insert the value of the variable `height_floor` into the string, so that the div's height will change based on the input value.

Comment: thanks for teaching me template literals, saw them many times in other js codes but finally understood what they meant.